# How to show that $X_t$ is a semi-martingale?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Let $B$ be a one-dimensional Brownian motion with $B_0=0$. Let $f$ be a twice continuously differentiable function on $R$ and let $g$ be a continuous function on $R$. If the process
$$
X_t=X_0+\int_0^t (\frac 12 f''(B_s)-f(B_s)g(B_s))e^{-V_s}ds+\int_0^t f'(B_s)e^{-V_s}dB_s
$$
where $V_t=\int_0^T g(B_s)ds$.

(1) How to show that $X_t$ is a semi-martingale?

(2) Show that $X$ is a continuous local martingale if and only if $f''=2gf$.

---

(1) We know that $\int_0^t f(s)dB_s$ is a local martingale, then the second part is a local martingale. But how about the first part? I try to show that it is finite variation.

(2) It is clear that if $f''=2gf$, then $X$ is a local martingale. But how about the converse statement?

Comment: Hint : the $ds$ integral has finite variation because you can differentiate it w.r.t. $t$ and this derivative is well behaved.

Comment: So since $d(\int_0^t f(s)dB_s))=f(t)d B_t$, then $\int_0^t f(s)dB_s)$ is finite variation?

Comment: @KurtG. I am confused about the definition of finite variation. Why a function is derivative then it is also finite variation?

Comment: it has to have a *well behaved* finite variation - as I wrote . It is not hard to show that in an exercise. Pretty much every book on stochastic processes ( I am sure Kratzas-Shreve ) mentions this as well.